# Auto write code in qterminal

Tags: command-line, bash, usb

i have script like below :

```
#!/bin/bash
qterminal -w /media/amg/TO1 &&
sudo chmod -R -v 755 * <- ***how to make auto write in qterminal & auto enter***
exit
```

my questions is how to make chmod line auto write in qterminal & auto enter

regards,

Comment: Please clarify what you effectively want to achieve. You currently are providing solutions *you* think will work (Y problem), but you fail to clearly outline your real problem (X). Edit your question to improve clarity. 1) Indicate what you want to realize 2) Then indicate what is now in the question, i.e., what you attempted yourself.

Comment: It looks like you want to open a terminal and run a command in it? `qterminal` has an `-e` option, so maybe put the command in a script and do `qterminal -e /path/to/script`.